# why does my rendering look so lo-fi

Tags: rendering

I followed a [tutorial to create sparks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XFz-wqv3Kc).

However, my rendering looks so lo-fi. Is there something I am missing? Is it graphic card? This is M1 Max or is there a setting I need to configure.

[image: screenshot of the configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noise comes primarily from not enough sampling. So most likely, unless you messed up with other things, you only have to play with these settings:

[image]

You set your viewport render to 1024 samples, which can be enough when coupled with some denoise, but you also have 0.1 noise threshold which makes the adaptive-sampling drop samples really quickly. Enabling the viewport denoise can help, but might look a bit mushy because there is still too much noise for it to give a good result:

[image]

Using OpenImageDenoise instead of OptiX's denoise can help a bit, though it's slower, don't bother with it if your render are already slow.

The next step is to add more samples. But disable the noise Threshold so to really see what your sampling looks "at its best". If you struggle with performances, use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to draw a render region that restrains the render to that specific area. Then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to remove the render region.
Once you found a value that seems to give something you like, enable Noise Threshold again and fine tune it to keep a nice looking render but faster.
Personally I never find *0.1* decent enough, I rather start as low as *0.01* and go even lower for the scenes that need it. Sometimes, I keep it disabled because it can't help but remove details I need.

[image]

Don't forget to adapt your render settings after that.

Answer (score 3):

I would enable *Motion Blur* as you mentioned in another question and add some glare. Note that the *Bloom* setting only works in *Eevee* renders and *Material Preview* mode. If you want to have glare/bloom in *Cycles* you need to add it in the *Compositor* with *Glare* nodes:

[image]
<sup>Cycles render, denoiser enabled, max 32 samples</sup>

**Note:** 1) the *Particle Info* node works only in Cycles. 2) You need to render out an image first then you can see it in the compositor.

An alternative for *Eevee* would be to use *Simulation Nodes* (Blender 3.6) and create your own particle system with some vector math. Then you can use the *age* attribute in the shader and render it with *Eevee* ([example tutorial](https://youtu.be/EkMOm4dDYSw?feature=shared)).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't messed with the particle system , first enable the *denoiser* in the *viewport* , then adjust *lighting* settings : *Intensity* , *Light paths* , *Reflections* . This might help a little bit

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the denoiser located under sampling -> viewport options.